# How can different scenes be linked for video editing?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, linked-data

I’ve just started learning about linking, and I think I’ve made a fundamental mistake — the thing is I have multiple Blender files going, one for each scene instead of having them as various scenes within the same single Blender file. I wanted to bring them all together into one master file for video editing but in a way that if I made changes to any of the other files, the one master file would reflect any of those changes. So I started learned about linking and I started linking to scenes and doing my video editing - but the scenes are each in their own Blender file. It kind of works, but I don’t think the master files reflects the updates to the scenes in the other individual files. I’ve already done so much video editing in the master file though - should I just append all these scenes into the video editing file, as separate scenes but all together in the master file? I’m really sort of at a loss